# Variable in "where" filter with Axios and Loopback

Tags: axios, loopbackjs

I'm in trouble to use variables in an Axios request to a Loopback(v3) API.

**What works?**
If I use the "REST notation" it works well:

```
 getInfo() {
   axios.get('http://myIp/api/tabs?filter[where][name]=' + this.name).then(response => {
     this.tabs = response.data
})
```

**What doesn't work yet:**

I can't translate the "REST notation" to the "Node notation" that I would prefer to use here.

**What I tried already:**

```
axios.get('http://myIp/api/tabs?filter={"where":{"name": this.name }}).then(response => {
        this.tabs = response.data  
})
```

I realise that with single quotes around the whole request, I can't get variable interpolation. But if I use double quotes, I don't know how to escape the ones used for the reserved words like "where", ...

What would be the correct way to use variables in this context?

Comment: I found a working solution but I'm not sure I understand all its whereabouts so I present it as a comment at first before make it maybe my own answer: Things work correctly if I format the Axios query like this: `axios.get('http://myIp/api/tabs?filter={"where":{"name": "'+this.name+'" }}').then(response => {this.tabs = response.data  
})` It's the first time I encounter this + sign around the variable name and I'm not sure of the meaning and couldn't find something relevant explaining this...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
axios.get('http://myIp/api/tabs').then(response => {
     this.tabs = response.data.filter(b => b.name === this.name)
```

It should work.
the main trick is response.data.filter() then give your filter logic inside the filter().

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to run something like this:

```
let value = "John";

let filter = {
   where: {
     name: value
   }
};
axios.get('http://myIp/api/tabs?filter=' + JSON.stringify(filter)).then(response => {
   this.tabs = response.data  
});
```

This way you will be sure that object is constructed in a proper way and you won't pass full object into the request, also you won't get lost with opening and closing brackets/parentheses

Comment: Thks, I'll try that! But maybe could you help me understand the meaning of these plus signs around the variable? Maybe I should ask this as a separate question, though.

Comment: sure. + sign means that you want  to join/concatenate strings. url you're sending needs to be a string

Comment: yes, concatenation. But here it looks like something else: why a plus sign on the right? It doesn't seem to me that the second plus sign in my example concatenate anything. And though I have to use this notation to make my solution work otherwise I get an error. I'd like to understand this clearly before using this (working) solution in production.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I will try to split this in smaller chunks and I need to add another answer to that becasue it's too long for a comment:

1. axios.get

**axios.get**('http://myIp/api/tabs?filter=' + JSON.stringify(filter)).then(response => { ... });

This expects a url as a string. since it's GET request, you cannot pass variables in the different form than in request url as variables, eg. http://mypage.com?variable1=value1&variable2=value2

2. argument

axios.get('http://myIp/api/tabs?filter=' + **JSON.stringify(filter)**).then(response => {
   this.tabs = response.data
});

Making super complicated urls can be a bit frustrating and not readable. fortunately, in loopback you can pass in an object instead. but to do this in the GET request, you need to pass it as a string. So you can call `JSON.stringify` on the object to make it a string.

3. concatenation

axios.get('http://myIp/api/tabs?filter=' **+** JSON.stringify(filter)).then(response => {
   this.tabs = response.data
});

Then, to pass that into URL you can concatenate your url with filter object stringified, like this:

```
# one method
url + JSON.stringify(filter)

# another method
var filters = JSON.stringify(filter);
axios.get(`http://myapi.com?filter=${filters}`, function(...))
```

Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

```js
axios.get('http://myIp/api/tabs?filter={"where":{"name":'+this.name }})
  .then(response => {
     this.tabs = response.data
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.